# Proof of Primal-Dual Linear programming Problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

consider the linear programming problem:

Maximize:

$$
\sum_{\bar{s} \in S} \alpha (\bar{s}) v(\bar{s})
$$
s.t.
$$
  c(\bar{s},\bar{a})+ \lambda \sum_{\bar{s}' \in S } p(\bar{s}'| \bar{s},\bar{a}) v(\bar{s}' ) \geq v(\bar{s}) \quad \forall \bar{s} \in S, \bar{a} \in A_\bar{s} \\
\alpha (\bar{s}) \geq 0 \text{ and } \sum_{\bar{s} \in S} \alpha (\bar{s}) =1
$$

Prove that the dual linear program is:

Minimise:

$$
 c(\bar{s},\bar{a}) + \sum_{\bar{s}' \in S } p(\bar{s}'| \bar{s},\bar{a}) v(\bar{s}') \quad \forall \bar{s} \in S
$$

Comment: I tried with the lagrangian of the primal problem but I don't know how to get to dual problem.I don't have much knowledge about optimization.

Comment: Because the LP you've given is the linear programming form of a Markov Decision Process, this problem is quite standard. I'm sure you can find the answer if you search along those lines. If not, I'll post a solution when I get some time.

Comment: @David Can you just give me any source to proceed. The sources which I have looked simply state them without proving them. I want to understand the proof.

Comment: @MUH sorry I don't have time at the moment to go routing around for a source, but I'd imagine a standard text like Puterman's *Markov Decision Processes* would have this in it.